# Implementation of SHA-1 yields different hashes than the `java.security` implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, hash, sha

I am trying to implement the SHA-1 algorithm in Java 11, and while testing the hashing algorithm I get different hashes than when hashing with the `java.security` implementation of SHA-1.

The pseudocode I attempted to follow can be found [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1).

```java
public static byte[] hash(byte[] message) {
    int h0 = 0x67452301;
    int h1 = 0xEFCDAB89;
    int h2 = 0x98BADCFE;
    int h3 = 0x10325476;
    int h4 = 0xC3D2E1F0;

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    out.writeBytes(message);
    out.write(0x00000080);
    while (out.size() % 64 != 56) out.write(0x00000000);
    out.writeBytes(ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putLong(message.length).array());
    byte[] data = out.toByteArray();

    for (int j = 0; j < data.length / 64; ++j) {
        int[] w = new int[80];
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
            w[i] = ByteBuffer.wrap(data, j * 64 + i * 4, 4).getInt();
        }

        for (int i = 16; i < 80; ++i) {
            w[i] = leftrotate((w[i - 3] ^ w[i - 8] ^ w[i - 14] ^ w[i - 16]), 1);
        }

        int a = h0;
        int b = h1;
        int c = h2;
        int d = h3;
        int e = h4;

        for (int i = 0; i < 80; ++i) {
            final int f, k;
            if (i < 20) {
                f = (b & c) | ((~b) & d);
                k = 0x5A827999;
            } else if (i < 40) {
                f = b ^ c ^ d;
                k = 0x6ED9EBA1;
            } else if (i < 60) {
                f = (b & c) | (b & d) | (c & d);
                k = 0x8F1BBCDC;
            } else {
                f = b ^ c ^ d;
                k = 0xCA62C1D6;
            }

            int t = leftrotate(a, 5) + f + e + k + w[i];
            e = d;
            d = c;
            c = leftrotate(b, 30);
            b = a;
            a = t;
        }

        h0 += a;
        h1 += b;
        h2 += c;
        h3 += d;
        h4 += e;
    }

    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(20);
    buffer.putInt(h0);
    buffer.putInt(h1);
    buffer.putInt(h2);
    buffer.putInt(h3);
    buffer.putInt(h4);

    return buffer.array();
}

public static int leftrotate(int x, int c) {
    return (x << c) | (x >> (32 - c));
}
```

To test this out, I attempt to hash a random array of n bytes, and compare the hash to the one obtained by

```java
MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1").digest(message)
```

I get different hashes.
Is there any mistake in my implementation above? Could the error come from somewhere else?

Comment: *I get different hashes. Is there any mistake in my implementation above?* If you get different hashes, there **must** be a mistake in your implementation. **Or**, in the way you're comparing hashes.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It is not from the way I compare hashes. Then do you have any idea where the difference comes from? I followed the pseudo code, which I assume Java's implementation is also following. Then where is why mistake here?

Comment: Umm... you don't get the same result because you completely ignore the message input except to use it's length. Also ByteArrayOutputStream does not have a method called `writeBytes()`, and even if every thing else were correct you haven't shown the code for `leftrotate()`, so we'd never be able to answer your question. Please show more care in asking questions.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Sorry, mistake copying and pasting a previous version where I didn't fix this issue. Edited. The problem remains. Considering `writeBytes()`, it does. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#writeBytes(byte%5B%5D)). Using this one instead of `write` allows to not have to handle an `IOException` that would never be thrown anyway.

Comment: You code still doesn't compile. Just try compiling what you posted here.

Comment: Your are using an older version of Java.

Comment: If you need a specific version of Java then you should include that information in your question. I normally test things with Java 8.

Comment: My fault. Did not verify I was using an API not available in Java 8. Java 11 is the most recent LTS version of Java released which is why it is the version I am using. Edited my question to add that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two problems with the implementation. First, I was writing the size of the initial message in bytes and not in bits. Second, the `leftrotate` method was using the arithmetic right shift when it should have been using the logical right shift.